# Get page ID in user_register hook Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, user-registration

in my site I have 2 differents forms for registration. The difference between them that is when I use the second I update a meta info for a user that normally is blank.

I've added the Facebook SSO and works fine only for the first form.
When I use it for the second it doesn't recognize the origin and register the user as the first one (without update meta info).

I've tried to use the register_user hook

```
function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {
    global $post;
    if ($post->ID == 816) {
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_type', 'couple');
    }
}

add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 999 );
```

but this hook doesn't return the post ID.

How can I detect I'm in the second form and launch the update_user_meta function when the post id is 816?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using if ($post->ID == "816") ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {
$currentPageId = get_the_ID();
 if ($currentPageId == 816) {
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_type', 'couple');
 }
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 999 );
```

Try this one it will surely give you the current page id..

Comment: Unfortunately not.
I'm sure the action is correct because without If it works.

Comment: function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {
 //$currentPageId = get_the_ID();
 //if ($currentPageId == 816) {
  update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_type', 'couple');
 //}
}

works but I cannot use it without condition because all registrations will reproduce this action

Comment: Nope, the meta field remains blank, and is really strange.
Probably the post ID can't be recovered from this kind of hook. The only param that is passed with the hook is the user id. You know if there's a way to pass another value in the hook?

Comment: Than you can do one more thing you can put the submit button condition. that will surely help you and you do not required to put the page id in the code as well.